# Some question on the Jordan Holder series or composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $G_1, G_2$ be group and $\pi_1$ is a representation of $G_1 \times G_2$ which has finite length.
Let $\rho_1$ is a 1-dimension representation of $G_1$ and $\rho_2$ is a (possibly infinite dimensional) representation of $G_2$.

Suppose that $\pi_1$ has a composition series whose all irreducible factor modules (i.e. subquotient modules) are of the form $\sigma_1 \boxtimes \sigma_2$, where $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are infinite dimensional irreducible representations of $G_1$ and $G_2$, respectively.

Then I am wondering why the two Hom-space $\operatorname{Hom}_{G_1 \times G_2}(\pi_1, \rho_1 \boxtimes \rho_2)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{G_1 \times G_2}(\rho_1 \boxtimes \rho_2, \pi)$ is zero.

I think if I know one of it, then I would know the another.

I would appreciate if you shed a light on this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think it follows from the fact that every subquotient module of $\rho_1 \boxtimes \rho_2$ should be of the form $\rho_1 \boxtimes \rho$ where $\rho$ is a subquotient of $\rho_2$.

Am I right?